# Python: readlines() with tar-file gives StreamError: seeking backwards is not allowed. What is wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, tarfile

Ok, I saw similar questions but not exactly the same. And I can't figure out what is really wrong with this python code:

```
import tarfile

tar_file = tarfile.open('something.tgz', mode="r|gz")
txt_file = tar_file.extractfile('inner.txt')
lines = txt_file.readlines()    
txt_file.close()
tar_file.close()
```

It gives `StreamError: seeking backwards is not allowed` due to `readlines()`.
But this fact looks strange to me and I try to understand what I miss here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
tar_file = tarfile.open('something.tgz', mode="r|gz")
```

According to the [`tarfile.open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) docs, the correct `mode` should be either `"r"` - *Open for reading with transparent compression (recommended)* or `"r:gz"` - *Open for reading with gzip compression*. Using the pipe `|` character creates a stream:

> Use this variant in combination with e.g. `sys.stdin`, a socket file object or a tape device. However, such a `TarFile` object is limited in that it does not allow random access

which is where you ran into problems with `readlines()` and `seek()`. When I changed that pipe `|` to a colon `:`, your code worked fine.

Comment: `txt_file.seek(0)` gives `AttributeError: '_Stream' object has no attribute 'seekable'`

Comment: @StarterKit see the accepted answer in the link in my comment above. Basically, you'll need to convert the `Stream` object into an `io.StringIO` object, then you can use `readlines()` (or `read()` or `seek()` or any other file object method) on it.

Comment: yes, I saw that answer but probably I misunderstood it. I see that they use `tmpfile = BytesIO()` there. But my understanding - it was done to store data from FTP locally. Later they open this `tmpfile` with `tarfile` and code is very similar to mine. So, may you elaborate a bit more about the difference with my code? I can't clearly see it.

Comment: @StarterKit ok, I figured it out. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! This was my fault. I use mode rarely in this way and copy-pasted it in a wrong way. Thanks again for explaining my mistake.